# PowerBI: Appending tables with calculated columns

Tags: append, powerbi

i have uploaded into Power BI 4 Tables: 1) Exchange Rates 2) Ledger Tree 3) Actuals results 4) Forecast.
Tables 3 and 4 had different columns or information (eg. 3 showed values by ledger in usd and 4 in local currencies;  table 3) is not showing the ledger currency while Table 4 does), so I had to add in both several calculated columns (including looking values from tables 1 and 2) to make them look alike.

I would like now to put table 3 and 4 above one another one but I am not sure how to do it?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you added the calculated columns in the query designer (Power query) or the report designer (Power Pivot)

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query to Union tables use [append query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/append-queries-power-query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a)

When selecting this, you can add to the existing query, or create a new table from the appended tables. If you do append you can select the old tables no longer used, and turn off 'Enable Load' so the reference table isn't loaded into the Power Pivot

In DAX, you can union tables using the [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax) function

Comment: Hi and thanks  i added the calculated queries in the report designer so, unfortunately, I cannot append. Using Union is a good idea I will have to use select columns to have the same order. For the moment I used 2 variables A) for Actuals (sumx filter from table (3) ) and B) for forecast from  Table (4) and the as a return I have added Actuals + Forecast. It works but it is not convenient like having all in the same table. Btw in power query can i add calculated columns filtering data from other tables?